# Recordset retrieves only first row

Tags: excel, vba, oracle11g, adodb

I am trying to retrieve records from Oracle SQL database and write them into a dictionary. Catch is that this code works as expected on my machine but no on my coworker's. On his end `Recordset` retrieves only one record even if that `Recordset` has `RecordCount` higher than one, meanwhile that same query pull up multiple records for me.

Initially I thought that `MoveNext` method is causing problems but once I switched to `GetRows` method issue persists. Anyway since this code works on my machine I'm fairly certain that my code correct, but you never know so I am including function in question here. The commented part contains the loop when I was using `MoveNext` but like I said changing that loop does not help with my problem.

```
Public Function WriteQueryToDict(SQL As String) As Dictionary
    'First column of the query must contain key that will be used to locate records in the dictionary
    'Output is a dictionary with first column as key, and the rest in an array that is indexed from 0 
    Dim Results As Recordset
    Dim ResultsArray() As Variant
    Dim cursorField As Integer
    Dim cursorRow As Integer
    Dim Output As Dictionary
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim record() As Variant
    
    Set Results = RunQuery(SQL)
    
    Set Output = New Dictionary
    If Not (Results.BOF And Results.EOF) Then
        ' New loop
        ResultsArray = Results.GetRows()
        ReDim record(0 To (UBound(ResultsArray, 1) - 1))
        
        For cursorRow = 0 To UBound(ResultsArray, 2)
            key = ResultsArray(0, cursorRow)
            For cursorField = 1 To UBound(ResultsArray, 1)
                record(cursorField - 1) = ResultsArray(cursorField, cursorRow)
            Next
            Output.Add key, record
        Next
        ' Original loop
        'Results.MoveFirst
        'Do
        '    For cursorField = 1 To Results.fields.Count - 1
        '            record(cursorField) = Results.fields(cursorField).Value
        '    Next
        '
        '    key = Results.fields(0)
        '    Output.Add key, record
        '    Results.MoveNext
        'Loop Until Results.EOF
    End If
    Set WriteQueryToDict = Output
End Function
```

In case this might be relevant this is function that does the actual connection + querying:

```
Private Function RunQuery(SQL As String) As Recordset
    Dim Username As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim DBConn As ADODB.Connection
    
    Username = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuration").Range("C3").Value
    Password = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuration").Range("C4").Value
    Set DBConn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    With DBConn
        .Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;user id = " & Username & "; password = " & Password
        .CONNECTIONSTRING = "Data Source=" & DB
        .Open
    End With
    
    Set RunQuery = DBConn.Execute(SQL)
End Function
```

I am guessing that this has to do with some setting set outside of my code, my colleague has no knowledge to configure oracle drivers on his own so I am at loss as to what tis might be. Anyway I've never seen my code produce such differences between two different machines so I'm not sure what am I looking for to fix this problem, I will share additional details as needed if you can tell what might be missing here.

Thank you

UPDATE:

When debugigng I setup a breakpoint inside WriteQueryToDict right before the loop starts, that way I was able to Play with Recordset itself first check the `RecordCount` property to make sure that we have records to iterate over last time I ran this on his machine I saw about 60 records, then call `MoveFirst` and my epectation is that now I will be able to call `MoveNext` 60 times before `EOF` turns true, instead it turn true after first call. while at it I tried setting `cursorLocation` to Client but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: Do you have multiple databases ?  Is it possible your colleague is querying a different database due to some difference(s) in their TNSnames entries?  Is your colleague running the exact same SQL?

Comment: ...or is it possible the issue is downstream of `WriteQueryToDict` ?  What debugging it any have you been able to do ?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams thank for getting back to me, so I'm pretty sure that he is connecting to same database in RunQuery function I sue constant `DB` that includes DSN that I hardcoded in code base so its the same thing, as far as debugging I'll include more details in question itself.

Comment: How did you get the recordcount?  Typically you have to do a MoveLast before you can get a reliable count - did you then do a MoveFirst before entering the loop?